# Get Hosted service details with GET Request URI with fiddler

Tags: azure, fiddler

As per [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx) i was testing GET request with fiddler but it gives me 403 error.

My request header was like below

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: management.core.windows.net
x-ms-version: 2011-10-01
```

Also as per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460801.aspx) this is due to authentication, if i am correct then how can i pass certification info with get request and able to get 200 (OK) status and result?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to provide the management certificate in the Request Builder with fiddler.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460782.aspx) on [how to authenticate management requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460782.aspx) with code samples.

You may also take look at the [codeplex wrappers](http://easyazure.codeplex.com/) to the management service, which will make your coding easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the request using Internet Explorer with Fiddler on, as you normally would. Then go to request builder tab in Fiddler. Drag and drop the successful request on to the tab and you should be able to get all the details.

Comment: I am getting this type of error on browser after selecting certificates >>MissingOrIncorrectVersionHeaderThe versioning header is not specified or was specified incorrectly.

Comment: if i would like to make this request by code then how can I pass certification info?