# Is there a way to call Windows Azure Service Management REST APIs without writing program code

Tags: azure

We are looking for a tool which can call Windows Azure Service Management REST APIs directly (i.e. without writing source code) so that operators can easily call them.

What we found so far is:

- Fiddler cannot call them. [Source: [Get Hosted service details with GET Request URI with fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410794/get-hosted-service-details-with-get-request-uri-with-fiddler) ]
- cURL can call them. [Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsazuremanagement/thread/f1cf3322-a8e3-4179-a35e-6bfb2fd55075 ] So we now use cURL but cURL is a CUI program but GUI program is much easier for operators. And we need extra work to convert certificate (=.pfx) to .pem.

Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets ( http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/documentation ) is also one of our options now but it is much better if we can call REST APIs directly. The reasons are 1)testing purpose. Some time we want to call REST API, not wrapped one. 2)There is some time lag before the Cmdlets implement REST APIs. (If I remember correctly, when Storage Analytics was introduced we need to call REST API to use it. But there was no Cmdlets at that time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the BURP Tool? Burp is a great Java based tool to use REST API directly in the GUI. You can use Burp tool to setup the PFX certificate used with Azure Management and then just type REST API and parameters to send request and get response.

You can download the tool below:
http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

I tested the tool today and then written the following blog to explain how to configure Burp to Manage Windows Azure subscription and services using REST API.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/16/windows-azure-management-using-burp-java-based-gui-tool-and-rest-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Azure Powershell Cmdlets, check out Cerebrata's Powershell Cmdlets @ http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/